# How to comprehend this syntax (a ? b ? c : d : c) in Swift

Tags: swiftui, option-type

I get below code in a SwiftUI tutorial, how to understand this line? I know the purpose is to set the seat color as accent color (blue) if selected otherwise leave it as default gray color.

But how to comprehend this syntax and what it is called as any terminology in Swift?

`.foregroundColor(isSelectable ? isSelected ? accentColor : Color.gray.opacity(0.5) : accentColor)`

```
struct ChairView: View {

    var width: CGFloat = 50
    var accentColor: Color = .blue
    var seat = Seat.default
    @State var isSelected = false
    var isSelectable = true
    var onSelect: ((Seat)->()) = {_ in }
    var onDeselect: ((Seat)->()) = {_ in }


    var body: some View {
       VStack(spacing: 2) {
           Rectangle()
               .frame(width: self.width, height: self.width * 2/3)
               .foregroundColor(isSelectable ? isSelected ? accentColor : Color.gray.opacity(0.5) : accentColor)
            .cornerRadius(width / 5)

           Rectangle()
               .frame(width: width - 10, height: width / 5)
               .foregroundColor(isSelectable ? isSelected ? accentColor :  Color.gray.opacity(0.5) : accentColor)
               .cornerRadius(width / 5)
       }
    }
}

struct ChairView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChairView()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is a nested [ternary operator](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-the-ternary-operator).

Not too familiar with swift, so I don't know my code snippet will be completely in line with Swift, but let's call it psudeocode for what your example does:

```
if a {
    if b {
        c
    } else {
        d
    }
} else {
    c
}
```

Comment: Yes, with the bracket I could understand it now, it is like ```a ? ( b ?  c : d )  : c``` but nested. Before this shorten format confused me with two ```: :``` and I don't know what it is called so hard to search it out.

Comment: @ChuckZHB If this answer is correct, please mark it so by clicking the check mark next to the answer score.

Comment: the parenthesis here are redundant as in expression a * (b * c)  or a + (b + c) . In other words, it doesn't exists other way how to interpret this expression. It is evaluated from left to right.